# Oracle Using Round and Multiplication in Same Select Statement

Tags: oracle, rounding, multiplication

The following code is rounding the end value. I was expecting this code to round the months_between only.

What I am trying to do is ...get the number of whole months between TermDate and PaymentStartDate. Then take that whole number and multiply it by PaymentAmount to get the TotalPayment.

```
tblPayment.PaymentAmount  * 
Round(
    months_between(
            to_date(last_day(tblPeople.TermDate)),
            to_date(trunc(tblPayment.PaymentStartDate, 'MM')))) as TotalPayment
```

I'd appreciate any help someone could provide. This is for a query I'm trying to build. My skill level = Low Level Frankenstein. Thanks!

Edit: Added sample data and results I am getting.

Sample Data:
Term Date 03/01/2021
Payment StartDate 03/21/2021
Payment Amount 790.03

Results:
MonthsBetween 1
PaymentTotal 790

Solved. I wrapped my code in To_Char formatted FM99999.00 and it returned 790.03 as text. I’m fine with that for my needs. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It *is* rounding result that `MONTHS_BETWEEN` returns. If PaymentAmount isn't a decimal number, you'll get the whole number as a result.

Comment: It will only round the `months_between` value. Please include sample data and the result you are getting - it looks like a problem with your data or expectation, not the query. If `PaymentAmount` isn't an integer than it's feasible your client/application might be rounding the result - try this in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer to compare what you see.

Comment: I've added sample data and result I am seeing. I'm thinking it is a data type issue because of the date values? But  monthbetween returns and integer not a string value, right?

Comment: So then, next question would be how do I set the PaymentAmount to Integer?

Comment: Yes, `months_between`  returns a number, and `round` keeps it as a number. And [that data and your query get 790.03](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bd84377c81b947f9fb45beb7a92ab940) as expected. Not sure that you mean about making `PaymentAmount` an integer - that seems to be exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Ok, regrouping my laymen thoughts... going back to the comment "client/application" might be rounding results" - The client application dumps it's results into excel. I have confirmed excel is not rounding. Is it logical to say the client application is rounding the result? If so, is there something Ican do to ensure client application does not round the result?  I agree the outcome of 790.03 is what should be expected from my code.

Comment: I used "to_char" on my code. I can confirm the client application is auto rounding something not sure what part but when using tochar is code producing a result with numbers after the decimal. Not sure how to stop it though.

Comment: Solved. I wrapped my code in To_Char formatted FM99999.00 and it returned 790.03 as text. I’m fine with that for my needs. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I wrapped my code in To_Char formatted FM99999.00 and it returned 790.03 as text. I’m fine with that for my needs. Alex Poole asked the right questions to help me piece it together. I'm new on here and don't know how to give him credit.